# Annotation and UI control within Wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, annotations

I have this viewmodel class

```
 public  class SchoolViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

      private  ObservableCollection<Student> _Eleves=  new ObservableCollection<Student>();

      public  ObservableCollection<Student> Eleves 
      {
          get {
              return _Eleves;
              }

          set {
              _Eleves = value;
              PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Eleves"));

          }
      }
      public SchoolViewModel( )
      {
      }


      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

I added this simple page :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SchoolViewModel x:Key="Locator" />
    </Window.Resources>
        <Grid  >
        <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Eleves, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" ></DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I need to extent the behavior of datagrid to make it more clever I mean, I had this model class :

```
 public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateNaissance { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to add some attributes to the class properties and make datagrid convert it to UI controls :

**For example :**

```
[DatePicker]
 public DateTime DateNaissance { get; set; }
```

will generate a column of Datepicker in the datagrid binded to `DateNaissance`.

How can I do this?What is the best and easier way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Student` class is clearly a **model**. According to MVVM, you shouldn't define in your **model** how its **view** should look like (e.g. using some attributes like `[DatePicker]` in your example).

Instead of this, you should define it in your **view** - that's the XAML markup in this case. Create a `DataTemplate` for your data item and describe all your *clever* things you want to have.

Please take a look on [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43525/WPF-DataGrid-Using-DataTemplates-for-auto-generate). There's a pretty good example how to flexible define `DataTemplate`s for auto-generated columns.

You could also consider [this Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950(v=vs.95).aspx).

Additionally, I would suggest you to read carefully about the MVVM paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via handling `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn`.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="OnDataGridAutoGeneratingColumn"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Eleves, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
```

Event handler:

```
private void OnDataGridAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
    PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor;
    IEnumerable attributes;

    if ((propertyInfo = e.PropertyDescriptor as PropertyInfo) != null)
    { attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(); }
    else if ((propertyDescriptor = e.PropertyDescriptor as PropertyDescriptor) != null)
    { attributes = propertyDescriptor.Attributes; }
    else
    { return; }

    ColumnAttribute attribute = attributes
        .OfType<ColumnAttribute>()
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (attribute != null)
    { e.Column = attribute.CreateColumn(myDataGrid, e.PropertyDescriptor); }
}
```

Attributes for annotating properties and for creating DataGridColumns:

```
public abstract class ColumnAttribute : Attribute
{
    protected internal abstract DataGridColumn CreateColumn(DataGrid dataGrid, object property);
}

public class DatePickerAttribute : ColumnAttribute
{
    protected internal override DataGridColumn CreateColumn(DataGrid dataGrid, object property)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        DataGridDateColumn column = new DataGridDateColumn();

        column.Binding = binding;

        PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
        PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor;

        if ((propertyDescriptor = property as PropertyDescriptor) != null)
        {
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath(propertyDescriptor.Name, null);

            if (propertyDescriptor.IsReadOnly)
            {
                binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
                column.IsReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
        else if ((propertyInfo = property as PropertyInfo) != null)
        {
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath(propertyInfo.Name, null);

            if (!propertyInfo.CanWrite)
            {
                binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
                column.IsReadOnly = true;
            }
        }

        return column;
    }
}
```

And finally our column with a DatePicker inside:

```
public class DataGridDateColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
{
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        BindingBase binding = Binding;

        if (binding != null)
        { BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty, Binding); }

        return textBlock;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        BindingBase binding = Binding;

        if (binding != null)
        { BindingOperations.SetBinding(datePicker, DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty, Binding); }

        return datePicker;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** This is not a MVVM solution beacuase you annotate properties of models (a view is specified in a model). If you want MVVM solution then do not use attributes and choose a DataGridColumn depending on a property type.